# How to convert ODataQueryOptions<DtoType> to ODataQueryOptions<EntityType> to query the underlying storage?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, automapper, webapi

I have a webapi controller using **ProductDTO** type for clients but the repository is using a **Product** type.

I would like to use odata on my endpoint. I receive the ODataQueryOptions parameter and I want to pass it to repository (implemented using CosmosDB).

I cant seem to figure out how to convert from `ODataQueryOptions<ProductDTO> to ODataQueryOptions<Product>`.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProductsController<ProductsDTO, Product> : ControllerBase
{
    IRepository<Product> _repository;
    IMapper _mapper;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<ProductDTO>>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductDTO> queryOptions)
    {
        var mappedQueryOptions = ... // convert 'queryOptions' to ODataQueryOptions<Product> ???

        var products = await _repository.Get(mappedQueryOptions);

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Product>, IEnumerable<ProductDTO>>(products));
    }
}
```

In my aspnetcore service composition I create and inject  automapper

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new ProductProfile());

    cfg.AddExpressionMapping();
});



internal class ProductProfile : Profile
{
    public ProductProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I managed to extract the queryoptions filter as a lambda expression *Expression<Func<Product, bool>>* (using automapper *MapExpression*) and passed it to repository , that works to a certain extent but I want to get the select , top, skip, etc. as well.

Any suggestions on how that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

can you review the example?

```
[ODataRouteComponent("api")]
public class UsersController : ODataController
{
    #region ctor

    private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    private readonly UserManager<AspNetUser> _userManager;

    public UsersController(IMapper mapper,
        UserManager<AspNetUser> userManager,
        ILogger<UsersController> logger)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    #endregion

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<UserDto> options)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        _logger.LogInformation("{UserUserName} is getting all users", user.UserName);
        return Ok(await _userManager.Users.GetAsync(_mapper, options));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int key, ODataQueryOptions<UserDto> options)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        _logger.LogInformation("{UserUserName} is getting user with id {Key}", user.UserName, key.ToString());
        return Ok(_userManager.Users.Get(_mapper, options).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == key));
    }
}


services.AddControllers(opt =>{}).AddOData((opt, _) =>
            {
                opt.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("api", EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModelv1());
            });


public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile() : base(nameof(WebUI))
    {
        CreateMap<AspNetUser, UserDto>();
    }
}


internal static class EdmModelBuilder
{
    internal static IEdmModel GetEdmModelv1()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
        builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();

        #region UserDto

        builder.EntitySet<UserDto>(nameof(DataListContext.Users))
            .EntityType
            .Page(25, 15);

        var f5 = builder.Function("Get");
        f5.Parameter<int>("key").Required();
        f5.ReturnsFromEntitySet<UserDto>(nameof(DataListContext.Users));

        #endregion

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. can you post the implementation for _userManager.Users.Get()? What is the returned type of that and how does it operate on ODataQueryOptions<UserDto> ?

Comment: "AutoMapper.AspNet.OData" you need to add this library.

Comment: I think that library works with EFCore right? but I dont use EFCore, neither EdmModel